# Assignment fails silently with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a very strange problem with Pandas.

On the last line, I get a KeyError. Pandas fails to retrieve self.Attitudes[user], despite the fact that it should have been set on the previous line.

Can anybody suggest what might be wrong?

https://sourceforge.net/p/commonground/code/HEAD/tree/CommonGround.py

EDIT

```
def add_document(self,user,uri,document):
    """Calculates the sentiment score, and topic vector for the document,
       and updates the users's attitude vector"""

    self.Sentiments.loc[(user,uri)]=sum([emotion['compound'] 
                                        for emotion in (self.vader.polarity_scores(sentence)
                                                        for sentence in sentence_splitter.split(document))])
    self.Topics.loc[(user,uri),:]=pandas.Series(dict(self.model[self.get_features(document)]))
    self.Topics.fillna(0.0,inplace=True)
    self.Attitudes.loc[user]=self.Sentiments.loc[user].dot(self.Topics.loc[user])
    self.modulus.loc[user]=numpy.linalg.norm(self.Attitudes[user])
```

`self.Sentiments` and `self.modulus` are `Series` objects. `self.Topics` and `self.Attitudes` are `DataFrame` objects.

`self.Sentiments` and `self.Topics` have heirarchical indexes (2 levels each).

Comment: Please copy the code to SO

Comment: Without running your code, you're adding a multi-index series to `Sentiments` and adding new rows using a tuple but then you only pass the user in the `loc` lookup which is why it failed, are you trying to return all rows for a user?

Comment: @EdChum That's correct.

Comment: I think you need this: `self.Attitudes.loc[user]=self.Sentiments.loc[slice(user), slice(none)].dot(self.Topics.loc[slice(user), slice(none)])` basically you need to pass `slice(none)` for the second level, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index